# Qual a diferença entre typeof(T) vs. object.GetType()

Tags: c#, .net

Qual a diferença?

Existe alguma diferença entre performance?

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença entre o uso de typeof e is](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/18246)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`typeof(T)` deve ser usado em **tipos**, não em **variáveis**. Seu objetivo é obter um objeto `Type` a partir de um tipo conhecido em tempo de compilação. Já o `object.GetType` retorna o tipo real de um objeto (i.e. seu "tipo dinâmico"), independentemente de qual seja a variável que o está referenciando (seu "tipo estático").

```
class Animal { } 
class Cachorro : Animal { }

Animal x = new Cachorro(); // O tipo estático é "Animal", o dinâmico é "Cachorro"
if ( x.GetType() == typeof(Cachorro) ) {
    // Executa um código só se o tipo do objeto for "Cachorro"
}
```

Mais informações [nessa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/983030/520779). É bom notar que ainda existe uma terceira opção para a verificação de tipos, o `is`, que leva em consideração a hierarquia de classes:

```
Object x = new Cachorro(); // O tipo estático é "Object", o dinâmico é "Cachorro"
if ( x is Animal ) {
    // Vai entrar nesse bloco, pois "Cachorro" é um subtipo de "Animal"
}
```

Comment: Bem valida sua resposta, entendi sim, obrigado

Comment: É importante ressaltar que a verificação `x.GetType() == typeof(Animal)` lança exceção caso `x` seja nulo, o que não acontece na verificação `x is Animal`, em que se `x` for nulo, o retorno é falso.

Answer (score 3):

Você só pode usar `typeof()` quando você sabe qual o tipo em tempo de compilação, e você está tentando obter o tipo do objeto correspondente. (Embora o tipo poderia ser um parâmetro de tipo genérico, por exemplo, `typeof(T)` dentro de uma classe com um parâmetro de tipo `T`.) Não sendo necessariamente necessário serem todas as instâncias desses tipos disponíveis para utilizar o `typeof`. O operando para `typeof` é sempre o nome de um tipo ou de tipo de parâmetro. Ela não pode ser uma variável ou qualquer coisa assim.

Agora compare isso com `Object.GetType()`. Isso vai obter o tipo real do objeto. Isso significa que:

1. Você não precisa saber o tipo em tempo de compilação (e geralmente
   você não sabe).
2. Você precisa que haja uma instância do tipo (de outra forma você não
   pode chamar `GetType`).
3. O tipo real não precisa ser acessível ao seu código - por exemplo,
   poderia ser um tipo interno em um assembly diferente.

Um ponto curioso: `GetType` dará respostas inesperadas sobre tipos de valor nulo.

> **Fonte:** [essa resposta no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537981/520779) (em inglês)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta