# Diferença entre o uso de typeof e is

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, tipagem

Em C# quando preciso verificar se uma variável é de determinado tipo, normalmente uso o operador `is`:

```
if(qualquerVariavel is int)
    Console.Write("A variável é int");
```

Sei que também é possível verificar o tipo de uma variável de outras formas, uma delas é usando `typeof`:

```
if(qualquerVariavel.GetType() == typeof(int))
    Console.WriteLine("A variável é int");
```

Qual a diferença entre esses dois operadores? Existem outros que "façam a mesma coisa", mas com uma pequena diferença?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre typeof(T) vs. object.GetType()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9661/18246)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) verifica toda a estrutura de herança do objeto;
- [`typeof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/58918ffs.aspx) devolve o tipo exato do objeto.

Para ilustrar melhor:

```
class Animal { } 
class Cachorro : Animal { }

var a = new Cachorro();

Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == typeof(Animal)) // false 
Console.WriteLine(a is Animal)                   // true 
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == typeof(Cachorro))    // true
```

Answer (score 16):

Um detalhe importante é que se a variável for `null`, o operador `is` retorna sempre falso.

```
string s = null;

s is string == false
s is object == false
s is int    == false
```

Escusado dizer, `GetType` não funciona com null.

À primeira vista, pode parecer um comportamento inconsistente. Mas Eric Lippert (ex-membro do comité de design da linguagem C#) explica porquê aqui: [What the meaning of is is](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/#more-1173)

> The fact that a null reference may be assigned to a string variable does not make the null reference a string, any more than the fact that your driveway can be empty means that an empty driveway contains a Honda Civic. The is operator does not answer the question “can I assign this reference to a variable of the given type?” It answers the question “is this reference a legitimate reference to an object of the given type?”, and null is not a legitimate reference.

Ou

> O facto de uma referência nula poder ser atribuída a uma variável `string` não faz da referência nula uma string; tal como o facto de uma garagem poder estar vazia, não significa que uma garagem vazia contenha um Honda Civic. O operador `is` não responde à pergunta: "Posso atribuir esta referência a uma variável deste tipo?". Ele responde à pergunta "Esta referência é uma referência legítima a um objecto deste tipo?", e `null` não é uma referência legítima.

Consequentemente, podemos também observar que uma referência não-nula do tipo `Nullable<T>` é também uma referência válida do tipo `T`, e vice-versa. Exemplificando:

```
int i = 1;

i is int  == true
i is int? == true

int? ni = 1;

ni is int  == true
ni is int? == true
```

Comment: Não funciona porque, obviamente, lança uma exceção hehe

Answer (score 10):

As respostas existentes já falam a diferença. Mas o C# 7 deu uma nova função para o `is` e ele se tornou absurdamente mais importante usando *pattern matching*.

Quando você precisa verificar o tipo do objeto? Quando você não sabe o tipo exato que está recebendo? O que você faz para usar esse objeto com o tipo que verificou?

Provavelmente faz um *cast* para o tipo e aí tem acesso aos membros disponíveis nesse tipo. Se não precisa acessar esses membros não tem que fazer o *cast*, e aí não tem que verificar que tipo é.

Como na maioria dos casos o *cast* seria o desejado o C# 7 permite que isto seja feito de forma automática.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Teste(DateTime.Now);
        WriteLine();
        Teste("ok");
    }
    
    public static void Teste(object qualquerVariavel) {
        if (qualquerVariavel is DateTime x) WriteLine($"A variável é DateTime e seu valor é {x.DayOfWeek}");
        if (qualquerVariavel is DateTime) WriteLine($"A variável é DateTime e seu valor é {((DateTime)qualquerVariavel).DayOfWeek}");
        if (qualquerVariavel is DateTime) //WriteLine($"A variável é DateTime e seu valor é {qualquerVariavel.DayOfWeek}"); //isto não compila
        if (qualquerVariavel is "ok") WriteLine($"A variável é string e vale ok");
        switch (qualquerVariavel) {
            case null:
                WriteLine("nulo");
                break;
            case int i:
                WriteLine(i);
                break;
            case string s:
                WriteLine(s);
                break;
            case DateTime d:
                WriteLine(d.DayOfWeek);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/moOML6). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxDwlh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Is.cs).

Note que a variável é declarada dentro do `if` ou `case` mas tem escopo do método, por isso não pode usar o mesmo nome em cada um. Isso ocorre porque ela não está dentro do bloco do `if`, a condição em si não cria novo escopo.

O uso do `switch` pode parecer que não está usando o `is`, porém assim como o `==` é implícito nele, o `is` também está lá mesmo que você não veja.

Note que o `is` tem uma forma de atuação fixa na linguagem e não respeita a sobrecarga do operador `==`. Então:

```
animal == null
animal is null
```

podem dar resultados diferentes, embora seja improvável. O primeiro pode ter o resultado alterado na sobrecarga de `==`, ainda que isso seja um erro. O `is` não pode, a linguagem sempre trata de forma específica. Veja a [lista dos operadores que podem ser sobrecarregados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).