# C# Converter objeto para uma lista desconhecida de objetos

Tags: c#, lista, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com uma questão aqui.

Eu tenho um objeto (object) recebido por parâmetro. Ele pode ser um objeto único ou uma lista de objetos (List).

Tem como eu converter o objeto para um objeto List SEM RECEBER O TIPO por parâmetro? Não quero o método assinado com .

Uma limitação importante: estou usando o framework 2.0. Então, nada de linq e outros scripts que poderiam ajudar minha vida a ser mais feliz... rs...

-- adicionando mais informações, aqui está a dúvida em si:

```
public class Conversor
{

    private class MinhaClasse
    {

        private string _meuNome;
        public string MeuNome
        {
            get { return _meuNome; }
            set { _meuNome = value; }
        }

        private int _minhaIdade;
        public int MinhaIdade
        {
            get { return _minhaIdade; }
            set { _minhaIdade = value; }
        }

    }

    public Conversor()
    {

        object lista = new List<MinhaClasse>();

        // E agora, como eu faço para transformar o objeto 'lista' em List<MinhaClasse> em tempo de execução para usar em um loop, por exemplo?
        // Lembrando que eu não quero assinar o método com o tipo genérico usando <T>, porque posso ter
        // que chamar o método de forma recursivo.


    }

}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloque seu código, dê uma contexto melhor para entendermos do que precisa e dar uma solução mais adequada. Precisamos entender que informação você tem disponível, o que deve acontecer se não for possível, se há garantias se sempre será possível, etc. Eu acho que tem solução melhor do que está pensando.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @bigown. Adicionei detalhes como vc soliciou.

Comment: O que faltou colocar é justamente como isto será usado. Do jeito que está basta tirar aquele `object` e declarar a lista e está tudo certo. Eu sei que não é isto que quer, mas a pergunta não deixa claro o que deseja.

Comment: Pelo que estou entendendo, você quer que o Conversor não tenha a responsabilidade de dizer o tipo, mas sim quem chame o método, certo?

Comment: No final das contas, o conversor vai me devolver uma string com os objetos em formato JSON... Mas como não tenho esse recurso nativo no .NET 2.0, estou escrevendo algo um pouco mais específico pro projeto que estou trabalhando. Esse projeto vai morrer em breve, mas preciso disso funcionando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua premissa está um tanto quanto errada. Mesmo você tendo uma instância `object` há como saber o tipo 'de verdade' deste objeto.

Pelo menos no C#, toda a herança funciona dessa forma: o tipo mais "ao topo da camada" guarda qual é o tipo real do objeto.

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/18246) tem mais detalhes sobre isso, mesmo não falando diretamente sobre o assunto.

Um exemplo simples: Imaginemos as classes `Automovel`, `Carro` e `Fusca`. Você poderá fazer o seguinte:

```
Automovel auto = new Fusca();

//Aqui é possível verificar se o objeto "auto" é do tipo Fusca ou algum outro

if(auto is Fusca)
    WriteLine("É um fusca")
else if(auto is Uno)
    WriteLine("É um uno");
else
    WriteLine($"É outro tipo de carro. Tipo: { auto.GetType() }");
```

Veja na prática, aplicado ao seu exemplo (usei uma lista de `string`, mas a ideia é exatamente a mesma):

```
using System.Collections;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> lista = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
        object obj = new object();

        Receber(lista);
        Receber(obj);

        ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Receber(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is IList)
        {
            WriteLine("É uma lista");

            foreach (var elemento in (IList)obj)
                WriteLine(elemento);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine("Não é uma lista");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Como eu disse no post, eu estou usando o framework 2.0. Não existe o IList sem passar o tipo genérico que ele representa. 
Não posso sair testando com vários if (object is List<coisa1...coisan>) pois seria, além de feio, péssimo para dar manutenção.

Comment: Por nada, conseguiu resolver o problema? Se sim, você pode escolher a resposta como correta marcando o **✓** que fica abaixo das setas para votar ***=)***

Comment: Desculpe... dei 'enter' antes de terminar de escrever. Ainda não resolvi a questão.

Comment: Perdão. Erro meu.
Achei a interface IList. 
Obrigado, me ajudou a solucionar o caso.

Comment: Se não me engano, a interface `IList` existe sim no framework 2. Mesmo que não existisse, é possível fazer essa verificação diretamente com o `List<T>`, a ideia é exatamente a mesma. Sobre os `if's`: você está complicando uma coisa que é simples, você pode validar da forma que bem entender, na resposta eu só mostro como você pode fazer.

Comment: Isso mesmo... vc tem razão :)
Obrigado mesmo...