# User Control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controles

Tenho o seguinte user control que está sendo utilizado em um Form:

```
public partial class CampoTelefone : UserControl 
{
    private void maskedTextBoxTelefone_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
    {
        //validações 
    }         
}
```

Após o usuário preencher o user control no Form eu passo ele para outra classe que efetua outros tipos de validações, o parâmetro `container` está recebendo um **`GroupBox`**:

```
private void valida(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control c in container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
    {
        valida(c);

        if (c is CampoTelefone && c.Tag.ToString() == "1") 
        { 
            /*outras validações*/ 
        }          
    }
}
```

Nesta parte `if (c is CampoTelefone && c.Tag.ToString() == "1")` eu preciso acessar as propriedades de `c` que no caso é o meu user control, porém suas propriedades não estão acessíveis, mesmo passando uma nova instancia do user control para o método que executa o `foreach`. As propriedades que consigo acessar são somente as que defini no momento da implementação do user control.

Nesta parte do código utilizando o controle `TextBox` funciona corretamente:

```
foreach (Control c in container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
    valida(c);
    if (c is TextBox && c.Tag.ToString() == "1")
    {
        // faço mais validacoes
    }
}
```

Eu exclui a parte do código das verificações por questão de espaço da pergunta, e utilizei o `campoTelefone` para simplificar.

Qual seria a solução para este problema?

Comment: O parágrafo onde você diz **`O problema é o seguinte...`** ficou muito confuso. Se você conseguir [edit] sua pergunta e explicar melhor, eu tenho certeza que posso te ajudar com isso ***=)***.

Comment: Ok, vou melhorar está parte.

Comment: @jbueno, veja se está mais claro.

Comment: Eu acho que saquei o seu problema, mas eu não entendo o que você quer dizer com **`As propriedades que consigo acessar são somente as que defini no momento da implementação do user control`**. Me dê um exemplo dessas propriedades.

Comment: Quis dizer propriedades do controle, exemplo: Tag, Mask, TextAlign, Locked, TabStop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que você está pedindo uma instância de `Control` no seu método, mesmo que seu objeto seja de um tipo derivado do mesmo a instância recebida será de `Control`.

Você só precisa converter este objeto para o tipo que deseja, veja (vou dar dois exemplos de conversão, escolha o mais adequado):

```
private void valida(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control c in container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
    {
        c = (CampoTelefone)c; //estoura uma exception se não for possível converter
        c = c as CampoTelefone; // c recebe null se não for possível converter

        valida(c);

        if (c is CampoTelefone && c.Tag.ToString() == "1") 
        { 
            /*outras validações*/ 
        }          
    }
}
```

Essa pergunta pode te dar uma ajuda pra entender o `is`: [Diferença entre o uso de typeof e is](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/18246)

Comment: Obrigado, agora ele está reconhecendo o tipo corretamente com typeof, porem as propriedades ainda estão com erro.

Comment: Você tem que fazer a conversão, veja ali **`c = (CampoTelefone)c;`**.

Comment: Resolvido. Obrigado.