# Receber por parâmetro uma Lista de objetos variados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, tipagem, parâmetros

Estou com o seguinte problema descrito no comentário:

```
public class Funcionario{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public DateTime DataContrato {get; set;}
}

public class Carro{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public bool IsUsado {get; set;}
}

// Aqui preciso receber uma lista que as vezes será de Funcionario e outras vezes de Carro;

public static MvcHtmlString(this HtmlHelper html, List<???> listaObj){
    //Aqui dentro eu preciso saber se a lista que estou recebendo no parametro é uma lista de Funcionario ou outros...
}
```

Comment: Está complicado entender, em qual momento é uma e outra, deve ter uma decisão a ser tomada, e qual é esse momento? por favor separe código de explicação!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deveria usar um método genérico aí verificar o tipo lá dentro. Mas o ideal seria fazer um método especializado para esse caso ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135702/101)). Poderia fazer algo assim:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;
using System;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        MvcHtmlString(new List<Funcionario> { new Funcionario() });
        MvcHtmlString(new List<Carro> { new Carro() });
    }
    public static void MvcHtmlString<T>(List<T> listaObj) {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Funcionario)) WriteLine("É lista de Funcionários");
        elseWriteLine("Não é lista de Funcionários");
    }
}

public class Funcionario{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public DateTime DataContrato {get; set;}
}

public class Carro{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public bool IsUsado {get; set;}
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/g01OLL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eCn0b8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/WhatType.cs).

O segredo aí, além de usar um tipo genérico, é verificar qual é o tipo que está sendo usado. Há duas formas de verificar o tipo:

- uma é em tempo de execução e é aplicado em objetos existentes. Usa-se o método [`GetType()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_GetType) disponível em todos os objetos. Ele retorna o objeto do tipo [`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que pode ser usado para fazer uma série de coisas, incluindo comparações;
- outra é usada em tempo de compilação e só pode ser aplicado a tipos diretamente. Usa-se o operador [`typeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (não é um método) para obter o objeto `Type` que pode ser usado para o que deseja, no caso foi usado para comparação. Obviamente é preferível o seu uso sempre que possível.

Essa é a forma de verificar se algo que você não sabe o tipo se é de determinado tipo. Como o [método é genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) e o tipo é variável, você tem que comparar o identificador que representa esse tipo genérico com o tipo que deseja. A comparação deve ser de tipos, por isso precisa pegar o objeto que representa o tipo (não estou falando do objeto do dado).

Então quando uso `typeof(T)` estou pegando qual é o tipo de `T`. Ele pode ser um objeto com as informações de como é composto `Funcionario` ou como é composto outro objeto que possa estar sendo usado na chamada do método (sugiro seguir os *links* para entender melhor a genericidade). Do outro lado eu uso `typeof(Funcionario)`. Eu sei qual é o tipo, mas eu preciso pegar qual é a representação do tipo, então o operador é obrigatório. Com as duas representações eu posso verificar se elas são iguais (na prática ele só verifica se é a mesma referência (endereço de memória do tipo, lembre-se que não estou falando dos objetos criados com dados desse tipo, falo do tipo em si).

Uso o termo tipo que pode ser uma classe, estrutura, enumeração, interface ou delegado.

Answer (score 4):

O que você precisa mesmo, é aprender a usar o operador `typeof` e o método `GetType()`. Com eles, você consegue verificar o tipo de uma determinada variável. Perceba que toda e qualquer classe do C# tem um método `GetType()`. Basicamente, você usa `typeof(T)`, onde `T` é um tipo qualquer. E `inst.GetType()`, onde `inst` é uma variável de um tipo qualquer.

Existe também o operador `is`, você pode [ver mais detalhes sobre as diferenças aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/18246)

Tem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. A mais simples é pedir um `object` e verificar qual o tipo dentro do método.

Também pode ser feito com `Generics` ou com herança, dependendo da arquitetura da aplicação, perceba que não estou dizendo que deve usar herança só porque precisa de um método assim, estou dizendo que é possível de se fazer, se já existir uma classe "base" entre os tipos que o método deve receber, herança possivelmente é a melhor saída.

Eu precisaria de mais detalhes pra dar uma resposta que se encaixe melhor no seu problema, ainda assim, é impossível dizer com certeza, porque só você sabe o quanto quer "engessar/dinamizar" isso.

Abaixo um exemplo usando `object` e verificando o tipo dentro do método.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lista1 = new List<Carro> { new Carro() };
        var lista2 = new List<Funcionario> { new Funcionario() };

        MvcHtmlString(lista1);
        MvcHtmlString(lista2);
    }


    public static void MvcHtmlString(object lista)
    {
        if(lista.GetType() == typeof(List<Carro>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lista de carros");
        } 
        else if(lista.GetType() == typeof(List<Funcionario>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lista de funcionários");
        }
    }
}
```