# Como saber se instância de classe Herda outra classe?

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, variáveis-de-instância

Estou usando reflexão para saber se uma classe herda outra, o que eu encontrei foi isso:

```
bool herda = typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B));
```

Mas eu quero fazer isso na variável pegando o seu tipo.

Eis a seguinte definição que eu preciso:

```
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

public class Principal
{               
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        // quero saber se classe B herda classe A através da variável b
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionada:[Diferença entre o uso de typeof e is](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/18246)

Comment: Uma dica: quase sempre não precisa disto, esta informação você tem sem precisar pedir para o código. Tem vários recursos que as pessoas usam porque não entendem o que realmente o código precisa, estes recursos existem para casos bastante raros, pode ser o seu, mas estatisticamente é mais provável que não seja.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como você quer checar o tipo "pai" a partir de uma variável de instância do tipo "filho", pode usar o operador `is`.

Se quiser usar o método `IsSubclassOf`, vai precisar fazer uso do método `GetType`.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.Write(b is A); // True
        Console.Write(b.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))); // True
    }
}

public class A { }

public class B : A { }
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdvwfB)</sup>

Comment: É recomendável usar o is para isso?

Comment: @Park Claro, é pra isso que ele serve.

Comment: De acordo com [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) o operador `is` é muito mais eficiente que o os métodos `Type.IsSubclassOf(Type)` e `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` pois gera uma única instrução `isinst` enquanto os métodos de reflexão geram um `StackFrame` a alocação desse `StackFrame` no`StackTrace`(alocação de memória e empilhamento) e a chamada em si do método .

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte:

```
typeof(B).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))
```

Veja em funcionamento no [Coding Ground](http://tpcg.io/FcQb2K)

Comment: Não consigo colocar a variável de instância dentro do typeof()

Comment: ajustei a resposta, tente agora

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o seu tipo com `GetType()` e usar `IsSubclassOf`

```
b.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(A));
```

[Type.IsSubclassOf(Type) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_IsSubclassOf_System_Type_)

> Determina se o tipo atual deriva do tipo especificado.

Funcionando em ***[dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3I2E9)***