# Como se faz uma condição que verifica o tipo de variável de uma var

Tags: c#, condição

Eu estava tentando fazer um programa básico pra fazer a regra de 3, mas me deparei com um problema, o usuário deveria escrever na prompt de comando as duas frações e assim eu as daria um valor var para identificar mais tarde se os caracteres seriam int ou string pois uma variável seria a variável aritmética como os valores x ou y, agora estou fazendo um if com a condição.

```
var valor1 = fracoes[0];
var valor2 = fracoes[1];
var valor3 = fracoes[2];
var valor4 = fracoes[3];

if(valor1 == string) // é nessa parte que tenho problema
{
  // aqui teria meu bloco de comando se o if funcionasse
}
```

Comment: De fato não faz sentido fazer essa verificação, é uma informação conhecida e esse `if` é completamente desnecessário. Pelo menos olhando esse código, pode ter algo que não sabemos, mas aí a pergunta não está clara. Pra falar a verdade eu acho que esse é um problema XY, você quer fazer outra coisa completamente diferente do que está descrevendo. A variável tem tipo conhecido em tempo de compilação e esse `if` é inócuo. Ou o bloco executará todas as vezes ou nunca executará, não há decisão a ser tomada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para verificação de tipo não se usa o `==`, e sim o `is`

Um exemplo:

```
if(varName is string) 
{
  // bloco
}
```

Veja funcionando: **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/S8bTWz)**

**Agora, precisa ver se faz sentido no seu caso. Provavelmente não!**

Provavelmente não faz, é quase certeza que já se sabe o tipo de antemão, sem necessitar de teste nenhum,  há algo no resto do código que já determina isso. Se já sabe o tipo, considero que testar com `is` (em runtime, o que é pior ainda) ja é praticamente um bug.

Leitura complementar:

- [Diferença entre o uso de typeof e is](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86493/70)

  Vale uma atenção a [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200206/70) sobre o que mudou do C# 7 em diante.